Replacement for Appimagelauncher?
I went to reinstall Appimagelauncher after rebuilding my system, however it fails to install. It appears to be no longer updated / maintained.
What is the replacement / preferred way to integrate Appimages into the system to be found on the app launcher?
There hasn't been an update since 2020:
https://github.com/TheAssassin/AppImageLauncher/releases/tag/v2.2.0
$ sudo dpkg -i appimagelauncher_2.2.0-travis995.0f91801.xenial_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package appimagelauncher.
(Reading database ... 407961 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack appimagelauncher_2.2.0-travis995.0f91801.xenial_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking appimagelauncher (2.2.0-travis995~0f91801+xenial) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of appimagelauncher:
 appimagelauncher depends on libcurl3 (>= 7.16.2); however:
  Package libcurl3 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package appimagelauncher (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for systemd (255.4-1ubuntu8.4) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1.1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for mate-menus (1.26.1-1build3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.27-2build1) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.12.0-4build2) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (2.4-4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 appimagelauncher

libcurl4 is installed
sudo apt install libcurl4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libcurl4t64' instead of 'libcurl4'
libcurl4t64 is already the newest version (8.5.0-2ubuntu10.4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 30 not upgraded.

searching for libcurl results in:
$ sudo apt search libcurl
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
fp-units-net/noble 3.2.2+dfsg-32 amd64
  Free Pascal - networking units dependency package

fp-units-net-3.2.2/noble 3.2.2+dfsg-32 amd64
  Free Pascal - networking units

fp-units-win-net/noble 3.2.2+dfsg-20 amd64
  Free Pascal - networking units dependency package

fp-units-win-net-3.2.2/noble 3.2.2+dfsg-20 amd64
  Free Pascal - networking units

libcupt4-2-downloadmethod-curl/noble 2.10.4+nmu2build2 amd64
  flexible package manager -- libcurl download method

libcurl-ocaml/noble 0.9.2-3build8 amd64
  OCaml curl bindings (Runtime Library)

libcurl-ocaml-dev/noble 0.9.2-3build8 amd64
  OCaml libcurl bindings (Development package)

libcurl3t64-gnutls/noble-updates,noble-security,now 8.5.0-2ubuntu10.4 amd64 [installed]
  easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library (GnuTLS flavour)

libcurl4-doc/noble-updates,noble-updates,noble-security,noble-security 8.5.0-2ubuntu10.4 all
  documentation for libcurl

libcurl4-gnutls-dev/noble-updates,noble-security 8.5.0-2ubuntu10.4 amd64
  development files and documentation for libcurl (GnuTLS flavour)

libcurl4-openssl-dev/noble-updates,noble-security 8.5.0-2ubuntu10.4 amd64
  development files and documentation for libcurl (OpenSSL flavour)

libcurl4t64/noble-updates,noble-security,now 8.5.0-2ubuntu10.4 amd64 [installed]
  easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library (OpenSSL flavour)

libcurlpp-dev/noble 0.8.1-5.3build1 amd64
  c++ wrapper for libcurl (development files)

libcurlpp0t64/noble 0.8.1-5.3build1 amd64
  c++ wrapper for libcurl

libghc-curl-dev/noble 1.3.8-14build2 amd64
  GHC libraries for the libcurl Haskell bindings

libghc-curl-doc/noble,noble 1.3.8-14build2 all
  Documentation for the libcurl Haskell bindings; documentation

libghc-curl-prof/noble 1.3.8-14build2 amd64
  Profiling libraries for the libcurl Haskell bindings; profiling libraries

libghc-hxt-curl-dev/noble 9.1.1.1-12build2 amd64
  LibCurl interface for HXT

libghc-hxt-curl-doc/noble,noble 9.1.1.1-12build2 all
  LibCurl interface for HXT; documentation

libghc-hxt-curl-prof/noble 9.1.1.1-12build2 amd64
  LibCurl interface for HXT; profiling libraries

libjsonrpccpp-client0t64/noble 0.7.0-2.2build2 amd64
  library implementing json-rpc C++ clients

librepo-dev/noble 1.14.5-3.1ubuntu4 amd64
  librepo - development files

librepo-doc/noble,noble 1.14.5-3.1ubuntu4 all
  Documentation for the librepo library (common documentation)

librepo0/noble 1.14.5-3.1ubuntu4 amd64
  librepo - shared library

librust-curl+force-system-lib-on-osx-dev/noble 0.4.44-4 amd64
  Rust bindings to libcurl for making HTTP requests - feature "force-system-lib-on-osx"

librust-curl+http2-dev/noble 0.4.44-4 amd64
  Rust bindings to libcurl for making HTTP requests - feature "http2"

librust-curl+openssl-probe-dev/noble 0.4.44-4 amd64
  Rust bindings to libcurl for making HTTP requests - feature "openssl-probe"

librust-curl+openssl-sys-dev/noble 0.4.44-4 amd64
  Rust bindings to libcurl for making HTTP requests - feature "openssl-sys"

librust-curl+ssl-dev/noble 0.4.44-4 amd64
  Rust bindings to libcurl for making HTTP requests - feature "ssl" and 1 more

librust-curl+static-curl-dev/noble 0.4.44-4 amd64
  Rust bindings to libcurl for making HTTP requests - feature "static-curl"

librust-curl+static-ssl-dev/noble 0.4.44-4 amd64
  Rust bindings to libcurl for making HTTP requests - feature "static-ssl"

librust-curl-dev/noble 0.4.44-4 amd64
  Rust bindings to libcurl for making HTTP requests - Rust source code

librust-curl-sys+http2-dev/noble 0.4.67-2 amd64
  Native bindings to the libcurl library - feature "http2" and 1 more

librust-curl-sys+openssl-sys-dev/noble 0.4.67-2 amd64
  Native bindings to the libcurl library - feature "openssl-sys" and 3 more

librust-curl-sys-dev/noble 0.4.67-2 amd64
  Native bindings to the libcurl library - Rust source code

librust-git2-curl-dev/noble 0.19.0-1 amd64
  Backend for an HTTP transport in libgit2 powered by libcurl - Rust source code

libstrongswan-extra-plugins/noble 5.9.13-2ubuntu4 amd64
  strongSwan utility and crypto library (extra plugins)

libulfius-dev/noble 2.7.15-2.2build1 amd64
  Web Framework for REST Applications in C - development

libulfius2.7t64/noble 2.7.15-2.2build1 amd64
  Web Framework for REST Applications in C

libwww-curl-perl/noble 4.17-10build4 amd64
  Perl bindings to libcurl

lua-curl/noble 0.3.0-12build2 amd64
  libcURL bindings for the Lua language

lua-curl-dev/noble 0.3.0-12build2 amd64
  libcURL development files for the Lua language

mpdas/noble 0.4.5-1build3 amd64
  AudioScrobbler client for MPD

python-pycurl-doc/noble,noble 7.45.3-1build2 all
  Python bindings to libcurl (documentation)

python3-librepo/noble 1.14.5-3.1ubuntu4 amd64
  Python bindings for the librepo library (Python 3)

python3-librepo-doc/noble,noble 1.14.5-3.1ubuntu4 all
  Python 3 bindings for the librepo library (common documentation)

python3-pycurl/noble 7.45.3-1build2 amd64
  Python bindings to libcurl (Python 3)

r-cran-crul/noble,noble 1.4.0+dfsg-1 all
  simple HTTP Client for GNU R

r-cran-curl/noble 5.2.0+dfsg-1build2 amd64
  GNU R modern and flexible web client for R

ruby-curb/noble 1.0.5-1build4 amd64
  Ruby libcurl bindings

ruby-ethon/noble,noble 0.16.0-1ubuntu1 all
  libcurl wrapper using ffi

ruby-typhoeus/noble,noble 1.4.0-3 all
  parallel HTTP library on top of ethon

tclcurl/noble 7.22.0+hg20160822-3build2 amd64
  Tcl bindings to libcurl

uacme/noble 1.7.4-2build3 amd64
  Lightweight client for the RFC8555 ACMEv2 protocol

wmget/noble 0.6.1-2build2 amd64
  Background download manager in a Window Maker dock app



All the Debian packages in the Releases tab target unsupported Ubuntu releases. You will have a tough time trying to install them. I'd suggest you use the AppImage instead.
